# Send mail in ASP MVC have Server Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sendmail

I'm have problem when practice send email in ASP MVC in tutorials:
[How To Send Email In ASP.NET MVC](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/268/how-to-send-email-in-asp-net-mvc).

I think problem in class:

```
public async Task<<ActionResult>ActionResult> Index(EmailFormModel model)
{
  todosomething
  return RedirectToAction("Sent");
}
```

When run website it show the below error:

[image]

**Solve:**
Thanks to @Simon C.
So, based on your comments, you have a POST contact method, but no way to navigate to the page yet ( just navigating to home/contact in your browser will send a GET request and since you have a `[HttpPost]` attribute, the route won't match). I think you need to add a GET method to your home controller to get you there:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Contact()
{
    return View(new EmailFormModel());
}
```

This means when you first navigate to /home/contact, you will hit the above method. When you post your form back to your site, you will hit the Contact Method marked with `[HttpPost]`.

Edit: As an aside, you will also need to add a method called `Sent` on your controller for when the email is sent successfully. The line `return RedirectToAction("Sent")`; will be looking for a method called `Sent`.

Comment: What is the name of your controller? And how are you registering your routes? Can you please add the code for that?

Comment: Routes register I'm set default config. "Home/..".

Comment: If your controller is named Home, the the URL should just be `localhost:52719/` or , if you want it in full `localhost:52719/home/index`. Having SendMail in the url means you are looking for a controller named SendMailController. (This assumes you are using IIS express)

Comment: Index or Contact is method in class HomeController.cs.
When redirect to Contact the URL is: **localhost:52719/home/contact** but it not work for me.

Comment: Could you make everyone a favor? Please remove email-specifics from your question, as it has nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, based on your comments, you have a POST contact method, but no way to navigate to the page yet ( just navigating to home/contact in your browser will send a GET request and since you have a `[HttpPost]` attribute, the route won't match). I think you need to add a GET method to your home controller to get you there:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View(new EmailFormModel());
    }
```

This means when you first navigate to /home/contact, you will hit the above method. When you post your form back to your site, you will hit the Contact Method marked with `[HttpPost]`.

Edit: As an aside, you will also need to add a method called `Sent` on your controller for when the email is sent successfully. The line `return RedirectToAction("Sent");` will be looking for a method called Sent.

Answer (score 0):

In EmailFormModel.cs model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web;
namespace MVCEmail.Models
{
    public class EmailFormModel
    {
        [Required, Display(Name="Your name")]
        public string FromName { get; set; }
        [Required, Display(Name = "Your email"), EmailAddress]
        public string FromEmail { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFileBase Upload { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Change class Contact in HomeController.cs to:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Contact(EmailFormModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var body = "<p>Email From: {0} ({1})</p><p>Message:</p><p>{2}</p>";
        var message = new MailMessage();
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress("name@gmail.com")); //replace with valid value
        message.Subject = "Your email subject";
        message.Body = string.Format(body, model.FromName, model.FromEmail, model.Message);
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        if (model.Upload != null && model.Upload.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(model.Upload.InputStream, Path.GetFileName(model.Upload.FileName)));
        }
        using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
        {
            await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
            return RedirectToAction("Sent");
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

And alter the Contact view (Views\Home\Contact.cshtml):

```
@model MVCEmail.Models.EmailFormModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", null, FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Send your comments.</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FromName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FromName)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FromEmail, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromEmail, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FromEmail)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Upload, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" name="upload" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Send" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

And Webconfig.cs is:

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp from="you@outlook.com">
      <network host="smtp-mail.outlook.com" 
               port="587" 
               userName="you@outlook.com"
               password="password" 
               enableSsl="true" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Thank @Dijkgraaf